# Error while runnig ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a video file to images:

```
ffmpeg -i XXXX.mp4 -r 1/1 $XX%03d.bmp
```

and I get the following error

> video:121501kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't see any error.

Comment: drop=297 frame=   14 fps=4.6 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=357 frame=   16 fps=4.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:16.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=411 frame=   18 fps=4.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:18.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=472 frame=   20 fps=4.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:20.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=524 frame=   20 fps=4.4 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:20.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=526    
video:121501kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

Comment: It extracts only 20 frames..

Comment: Edit your question and explain about the error for more information

Comment: In the future, please always include the full, uncut command line output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract all frames from a video, use

```
ffmpeg -i XXXX.mp4 -vsync 0 $XX%03d.bmp
```